# Apache2 : too many redirects with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

*Note* I saw few questions already with the isssue but none helped me out.

I getting too many redirects with the following `.htaccess` file. I'm not expert using .htaccess but I think it also takes care of `https` and I really don't have to worry about it at this momoent.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### Remove trailing slash from all URLs

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all these rules are wrong :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You check whether the request comes with `htpps` or not , if not you do nothing except looping because in this line `RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` you don't change `http` to `https` .

let's copy all rules here and change `http` to `https` in the first condition rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The rules above make looping because the first condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP} off` will be done again and again whenever second condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\. [NC]` happened.

let's make an example :

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com
```

This request will be handled by the first condition and would be redirected to :

```
https://www.yourwebsite.com
```

Then ,it will be handled by the second condition,because it could pass it, and would be redirected to :

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com
```

Again,first condition then second and so on .this will make more looping.

Change the first rules like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)   https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As i understand you want only to force requests under this condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.` into `https` because you except them .

**Note:** make sure you empty browser cache before test.